# Dynamic Image Table in Swift for iOS8

Tags: uitableview, swift, uiimageview

I am new to programming applications, although I have a rudimentary handle on it.
I would like to get user input for # of columns and # of rows, then create a table of images (identical) scaled to fit on the screen.
I would then like to be able to cycle through these and change their color one at a time.

I can program this in python (see below) but I have no idea how to do this graphically.
Thoughts?

```
print("Welcome to Well Tracker!")
r=input('number of rows? ')
while r.isdigit()!=True:
    print('invalid try again')
    r=input('number of rows? ')
r=int(r)
c=input('number of collumns? ')
while c.isdigit()!=True:
    print('invalid try again')
    c=input('number of rows? ')
c=int(c)
print('\nTap enter to cross of a well, \nenter anything else to end\n')
wellC=[0]*c
def showWell(well):
    print('The Well')
    for i in well:
        print(i)

def fillNumbers(matrix):
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
            matrix[i][j]=j+1
    return matrix

def makeWell(rows, collumns):
    i = 0
    well=[]
    while i<rows:
        well+=[collumns[:]]
        i+=1
    well=fillNumbers(well)
    return well
wellPlate=makeWell(r,wellC)
showWell(wellPlate)


def crossOff(well):
    end='';

    for col in range(len(well[0])):
        row=0
        while row < len(well):
            end=input();
            if end != '':
                return False
            well[row][col]='x'
            row+=1
            showWell(well)
def checkForX(well):
    xs=0
    for i in range(len(well)):
        for j in range(len(well[i])):
            if well[i][j] == 'x':
                xs+=1
    return xs

def main():
    platesComplete=0
    while True:
        wellPlate=makeWell(r,wellC)
        if crossOff(wellPlate) == False:
            break
        platesComplete+=1
    wellsComplete=checkForX(wellPlate)+platesComplete*r*c
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated:**

okay, my recommendation is to look to use a UICollectionView.  Example here:

https://github.com/bluedome/DragToReorderCollectionView

Comment: Thank you for the link. I'll go through it, however I don't think it is exactly what I am thinking of...

Comment: are you just looking for help on creating the user input and accessing it within your code?  if so, do the Tip Calculator tutorial in swift at the same site I linked to.

Comment: Not exactly(?) I want to make a grid of graphics, then be able to loop through and switch those graphics with a second image. I have user input for how many rows and how many columns and which way to loop through (down rows, or down columns). Now it is a matter of making the image on the screen

Comment: woah! That's really awesome! I am very impressed. I'll see if I can use this to figure out what it is that I am trying to do. Thank you so much for this guidance!

Comment: in general search GitHub for UICollectionView swift.  There will be some really good drop in from obj-C if you know how to incorporate those.

Comment: That means clicking the check mark right? Done. Yeah, I am struggling still with UICollectionView, but I think I've made good progress

Comment: Correct and thanks.  Regarding UICollectionView, github is your friend.  Search for things like UICollectionView and Swift